# Problems with output parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem when I run this procedure it gives me back an error trying to parse 'ok' to int but I dont want result to be int.

```
DECLARE @result_var nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(max)    

EXECUTE Sp_executesql
            @definition,
            @ParmDefinition,
            @result_var = @result_var output;
```

Code that is changing `@result_var`

```
SET @result_var = ''ok''; 

DECLARE @cursor CURSOR, 
        @name VARCHAR(100) 

SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR 
                 SELECT [NAME] 
                 FROM [iflvs08].mds.mdm.lv_budget_employee

OPEN @cursor
FETCH next FROM @cursor INTO @name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
   IF RIGHT(@Name, 1) = '' ''
   begin
      IF (Len(@result_var) > 1) 
         SET @result_var = @result_var + '','' + @name 
      ELSE 
         SET @result_var = @name 
   END

   FETCH next FROM @cursor INTO @name 
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that you declared but didn't set up @ParmDefinition variable.
It should be like this:

```
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(max)
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@result_var nvarchar(max) OUTPUT';    
EXECUTE Sp_executesql
            @definition,
            @ParmDefinition,
            @result_var=@result_var output ;
```

Comment: Thx there  @parmdefination was set to int , hard to fix others code i did not found this row :(